# Azure Synapse Pipeline is not found when triggered manually

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I have created a Pipeline in Azure Synapse that executes a simple copy activity within a for each activity.

[image]

When I test the pipeline using debug, the pipeline runs successfully. However, after adding a trigger to the pipeline and commiting the changes to Azure DevOps, the pipeline is not found when I trigger it manually.

[image]

I am asked to "publish" the pipeline, despite using Azure DevOps. Is there an additional step necessary after committing the changes to Azure DevOps to publish a pipeline trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to perform a trigger run , you need to publish your changes. Only commiting the changes doesn't suffice.

Please check the official documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I falsely assumed that "commiting" to Azure DevOps replaced "publishing"...

Comment: Just to add a tiny bit more.  Commit is basically like a 'Save'.  It saves your work progress, to the Branch you're working on, without affecting live.  So you could create a Development branch, do some work, get halfway through, and commit at the end of the day, knowing it's not going to affect live.  Once you're ready, you can merge your dev branch to Main Branch, and then Publish, which pushes Main into Live.

Comment: @Celador take note the collaboration git branch can be different from main branch ... so long as you publish to collaboration branch you can then run a trigger without pushing to main